# Vue.js binding data with document.createElement

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm integrating Vue.js to an existing project, and I'm stuck on the problem below.

Here is part of my code:

```
video = MicroEvent.mixin(document.createElement("video"));
video.autoplay = true;
video.ontimeupdate = function (evt) {
     ....
};
```

*video* is a DOM element, and I bind it to the data block.

[image]

I am then attempting to append it to the template through *v-html*
[image]

but it does not work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Show the Html parts

Comment: @Max I've added, please see the second picture. Thanks

Comment: try to copy the <video> tag directly to the template to verify that the link working. When you setup the video data ? Have you check the DOM if there are the video tag ?

Comment: `v-html` takes a string, not a DOM fragment. Why not just embed the video in the template and update the attributes as needed?